# Sum Number values in array of objects and Keep Group Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

```
var myArrayOfObjects = [{Group:MD,qtyA:4,qtyB:5},{Group:IL,qtyA:1,qtyB:3},{Group:FL,qtyA:5,qtyB:5}];

//RESULT I'M LOOKING FOR:
// [{Group:MD,Total:9},{Group:IL,Total:4},{Group:FL,Total:10}]
```

I'm initially using reduce to get the myArrayOfObjects but I can't figure out how to total everything and keep the Group in the object as part of the array

Comment: What are you tried so far?

Comment: You didn't say group names are unique or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and
[`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var myArrayOfObjects = [
  { Group: "MD", qtyA: 4, qtyB: 5 },
  { Group: "IL", qtyA: 1, qtyB: 3 },
  { Group: "FL", qtyA: 5, qtyB: 5 },
];
var result = myArrayOfObjects.map(({ Group, ...quantities }) => ({
  Group,
  Total: Object.values(quantities).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0),
}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will sum up all numeric values within a group. You should use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the result for each group and then use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to calculate the total quantity.

```js
const myArrayOfObjects = [
  { Group: "MD", qtyA: 4, qtyB: 5 },
  { Group: "IL", qtyA: 1, qtyB: 3 },
  { Group: "FL", qtyA: 5, qtyB: 5 },
];

const result = myArrayOfObjects.map((group) => ({
  Group: group.Group,
  Total: Object.values(group).reduce((total, quantity) =>
    typeof(quantity) === "number" ? (total += quantity) : total, 0
  ),
}));

console.log(result)
```

```css
/* StackOverflow snippet: console should overlap rendered HTML area */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: you follow the same approach I did, I already answer it!

Comment: Noticed after I posted it. There's a difference on how to choose the values to sum up though. Your approach will fail once there is another property that is not of type `number`. Not a problem for this question (and the fix is not hard), but might be one in the future, therefore I decided not to delete my answer. For the general approach I think there's only really one sensible option with `map()` and `reduce()`.

Comment: I tested the above in Chrome and it worked. But it's not working for me in Edge. Looking into that now

Comment: During testing, it dies when I hits the Object.values portion (in Edge). No error. Nothing. I thought maybe it was an ES6 issue so I converted it to ES5. Same results

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce this issue. It does run on Edge version `105.0.1343.50`. What do you get when you run e.g. `Object.values({test: 12})` in the Dev console? It should return `[12]` (an array with one value `12`).